# Save a file generated with Javascript inside streamlit to a directory

Tags: javascript, python, streamlit, web-mediarecorder

I have an audio file which is generated by a JS script integrated to my streamlit web-app with components.html, like this:

```
components.html(
                """
                <!DOCTYPE html>
                <html lang="en">
                <head>
                    <meta charset="UTF-8">
                    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
                    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
                    <title>Document</title>
                </head>
                <body>
                    <!-- Set up your HTML here -->
                    <center>
                        <p><button id="record">Record</button></p>
                        <div id="sound-clip"></div>
                    </center>
                    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
                        integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
                    <script>
                        // Set up the AudioContext.
                        const audioCtx = new AudioContext();

                        // Top-level variable keeps track of whether we are recording or not.
                        let recording = false;

                        // Ask user for access to the microphone.
                        if (navigator.mediaDevices) {
                            navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ "audio": true }).then((stream) => {

                                // Instantiate the media recorder.
                                const mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);

                                // Create a buffer to store the incoming data.
                                let chunks = [];
                                mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = (event) => {
                                    chunks.push(event.data);
                                }

                                // When you stop the recorder, create a empty audio clip.
                                mediaRecorder.onstop = (event) => {
                                    const audio = new Audio();
                                    audio.setAttribute("controls", "");
                                    $("#sound-clip").append(audio);
                                    $("#sound-clip").append("<br />");

                                    // Combine the audio chunks into a blob, then point the empty audio clip to that blob.
                                    const blob = new Blob(chunks, { "type": "audio/wav; codecs=0" });
                                    audio.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);

                                    // Clear the `chunks` buffer so that you can record again.
                                    chunks = [];
                                };

                                mediaRecorder.start();
                                recording = true;
                                $("#record").html("Stop");

                                // Set up event handler for the "Record" button.
                                $("#record").on("click", () => {
                                    if (recording) {
                                        mediaRecorder.stop();
                                        recording = false;
                                        $("#record").html("Record");
                                    } else {
                                        $("#record").html("Stop");
                                    }
                                });

                            }).catch((err) => {
                                // Throw alert when the browser is unable to access the microphone.
                                alert("Oh no! Your browser cannot access your computer's microphone.");
                            });
                        } else {
                            // Throw alert when the browser cannot access any media devices.
                            alert("Oh no! Your browser cannot access your computer's microphone. Please update your browser.");
                        }
                    </script>
                </body>
                </html>
            """
            )
```

This JS code basically records the user’s microphone via the browser and stores the file inside a Blob.

Is it possible to save the file generated by Blob() to a directory so that I can use it inside my Python script?

Answer (score 0):

You can save the file by using [download](https://github.com/rndme/download) js library ([cdn link](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/downloadjs/1.4.8/download.min.js)) as per my tests this always prompts a download request pop up asking you for save location.

- If u want to do that you can add  it after generating the blob add the cdn link and use

  download(blob, "audio.wav");
- Other wise this isnt a good option but you can save it as a blob on your browsers localstorage using the following code

  ```
         const fileName = `aaaaaa.wav`;
         // Save the audio clip to the user's computer.
         const fileReader = new FileReader();
         fileReader.readAsDataURL(blob);
         fileReader.onload = () => {
           const dataURL = fileReader.result;
           // Save the dataURL to localStorage
           localStorage.setItem(fileName, dataURL);
           console.log(`Blob saved to localStorage as ${fileName}`);
         };
  ```

This will save it into a key pair value in your browser "http+++localhost+8501" folder as my webpage was http://localhost:8501 then you can use the sqlite3 to fetch the file and convert the data to wav file
as follows

```
import sqlite3
import pathlib
path=pathlib.Path('[Firefox profile path]//storage//default//http+++localhost+8501//ls//data.sqlite')
db = sqlite3.connect(path)
cursor = db.cursor()
with open("Output.wav", "wb") as output_file:
    cursor.execute("SELECT value FROM 'data'  where key ='aaaaaa.wav'")
    ablob = cursor.fetchone()[0]
    # write operation
```

Im not sure how to convert the bs64 encoded blob to a wav file but thats all i could help out

### Alternative:

You could build a flask app which records and saves audio, its more easier,convenient and give you a lot more control than injecting HTML to the main streamlit app which reduces some control